# Microsoft Graph Creating Subscription When A New User Created

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-webhooks

First, I subscribed to receive notifications when users are updated, and **I received notifications when I updated any user.** However, my problem is that when I change the **ChangeType to "created"** I expected to receive notifications when a new user is created, but unfortunately, I didn't receive any notifications.

Am I wrong in my expectation? If my expectation is wrong, is there another way to achieve this?

My subscription settings below.

```
    var sub = new Microsoft.Graph.Models.Subscription();
    sub.ChangeType = "created";
    sub.NotificationUrl = "https://*********.eu.ngrok.io" + "/api/notifications";
    sub.Resource = "/users";
    sub.LifecycleNotificationUrl = "https://*******.eu.ngrok.io" + "/api/notifications";
    sub.ExpirationDateTime = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(10);
    sub.ClientState = "SecretClientState";
```

Answer (score 0):

> Am I wrong in my expectation? If my expectation is wrong, is there another way to achieve this?

You can create an alert using **Log Analytics workspace** when **Azure Ad** user is created.

I have followed below steps to create an alert when the **Azure AD** user is created.

1. I have created **Log Analytics Workspace** as below.

**Go to Azure Portal > Log Analytics workspace > create**

[image]

2. Once create a **Log Analytics workspace**, add **Active Directory Logs** to **LAW** as below.

**Azure Active directory > Diagnostic settings > Add diagnostic setting.**

[image]

3. Go to **Log Analytics workspace** and ran the below query to check **AD Activity** logs as below.

**Query to check when the Azure AD account is created.**

```
AuditLogs
| where Category contains "UserManagement"
| where OperationName contains "Add user"
| project TimeGenerated, OperationName,Category,InitiatedBy,Result
```

**Output:**

[image]

4. Create an alert as below.

[image]

6. Create an **Action Group** as below to send an email.

[image]

7. If Azure **AD account** is created, you will get an alert as below.

[image]

**Email Notification**

[image]

Comment: Thank you for comment VenkatV,

But ı need to do this using a webhook in the API.  This because when I recieve a notification for a newly created user, I need to take action on it using Microsoft Graph API

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to use a webhook?  I need to do something similar.